# Please explain the reason why E2 mechanism occurs

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, elimination

I known as that when the weak bases are reacting with 2° alcohol, E1 mechanism occurs. But, in the picture, E2 mechanism is occurred. Why E2 mechanism occurred?

In step [3]
Weak base : pyridine

[image]

Did I get it wrong? It is smith organic chemistry 4e, 309 page
[image]